# How to use @Grab against to resolve a dependency of type POM

Tags: groovy

I'm trying include the dependency spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.2.RELEASE.pom and with @Grab I'm not able to resolve it. Here below is the syntax that I have

```
@Grab('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.2.RELEASE')
```

Can you suggest me the correct syntax is above is wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: What's not working exactly? It seems to be correct.

Comment: Without knowing the actual error you are getting it's difficult to know what's going on. Classifiers can be added to Grapes by appending your String with `@pom`. But Groovy is picky about what follows the @Grab annotation (because Java is picky about what follows annotations in general) so you'd need to post some output